# Query works outside of stored procedure but inside of procedure it throws error

Tags: oracle, plsql

Select query works perfectly outside of package procedure, but inside procedure
it throws 'ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected' error.

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE
      v_general_number VARCHAR(11);
BEGIN
      SELECT 'Q' || TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Q') || '/'  ||   LPAD(TO_CHAR(SEQ_EDP_GENERAL_NUM_ID.NEXTVAL), '3', '0')  || '/' || TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'))) INTO v_general_number FROM DUAL;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_general_number);
END;
```

And it works pretty fine.

But inside stored procedure it throws the error above.

Here is my procedure:

```
   PROCEDURE save_request(p_name IN requests.suggested_name%TYPE,
                          p_urgency_type IN requests.urgency_type_id%TYPE) 
   AS

      v_general_number VARCHAR(11);

   BEGIN

   SELECT 'Q' || TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Q') || '/'  ||  LPAD(SEQ_EDP_GENERAL_NUM_ID.NEXTVAL, 3, '0')  ||  '/' ||  TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')))  INTO v_general_number FROM DUAL;

   INSERT INTO requests (suggested_name,
                          urgency_type_id,
                          general_number 
      ) VALUES (
          p_name ,
          p_urgency_type ,
          v_general_number );



    END save_request;
```

I can not see what is the problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I solved the problem after changing this:

```
SELECT 'Q' || TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Q') || '/'  ||  LPAD(SEQ_EDP_GENERAL_NUM_ID.NEXTVAL, 3, '0')  ||  '/' ||  TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')))   INTO v_general_number FROM DUAL;
```

To this:

```
SELECT 'Q' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Q') || '/'  ||  LPAD(SEQ_EDP_GENERAL_NUM_ID.NEXTVAL, 3, '0')  ||  '/' ||  TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE))  INTO v_general_number FROM DUAL;
```

And it worked.

But I still don't understand why the same query works outside of procedure, but throws error inside procedure.

Comment: Regarding why it works with second query - execute each separate section of both the "before" and "after" query and eventually you'll find the piece that isn't working. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SYSDATE` is already a date, so

```
TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

doesn't really make sense. You are doing an implicit conversion to a string, then an explicit conversion to a date, i.e. effectively:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, <NLS_DATE_FORMAT>), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Whether it works depends on your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'MM/DD/YYYY';
select TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;

TO_DATE(SY
----------
07/04/2018

select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;

TO_CHAR(TO
----------
2018-07-04

alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
select TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;

TO_DATE(SY
----------
07/04/2018

select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;

TO_CHAR(TO
----------
2018-04-07

alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY';
select TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;

ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
select TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;

ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Notice that the first two both 'work', but actually give you different dates. (Later in the month, after the 12th, the second one will fail too with an invalid month error.)

The session you are running the anonymous block from, and the session you are executing the procedure from, simply have different NLS settings. Which is why you should not rely on implicit conversion or on NLS settings...

Anyway, remove the unnecessary conversions:

```
SELECT 'Q' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Q')
  || '/' || LPAD(TO_CHAR(SEQ_EDP_GENERAL_NUM_ID.NEXTVAL), '3', '0') 
  || '/' || TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE))
INTO v_general_number
FROM DUAL;
```

or do the same thing with an assignment instead of selecting from dual:

```
v_general_number := 'Q' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Q')
  || '/' || LPAD(TO_CHAR(SEQ_EDP_GENERAL_NUM_ID.NEXTVAL), '3', '0')
  || '/' || TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE));
```

or even, just as an alternative:

```
v_general_number := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, '"Q"Q"/"')
  || TO_CHAR(SEQ_EDP_GENERAL_NUM_ID.NEXTVAL, 'FM000')
  || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, '"/"YYYY');
```

which uses character literals in the date format models to replave the concatenation of the slashes, and a format model for the sequence number so you don't need to then pad it with zeros. (And you don't really need a variable, you can do the same construction inside the insert's `values` clause.)